# How is it a single variable optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In example 5.4 of Convex Optimization book (by Vandenberghe and Boyd) they show that the optimization problem $$\min. f_0(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x_i),\\ \text{s.t. }a^Tx=b$$ has a dual problem $$\max. ~-bv-\sum_{i=1}^nf_i^*(-va_i)$$ with scalar variable $v$. Next, they say that the dual problem is a single variable problem. I do not understand how is it a single variable problem. Because in order to get $f_i^*(-va_i)$ we have to maximize over individual $x_i$'s. Where am I wrong in this understanding? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the single variable is $v$.

Comment: $a^Tx = b$, so $b$ is a number. In the 2nd problem you have $bv$, so $v$ is a scalar.

Comment: @angryavian yes I know they say that the single variable is $v$ but in the computation of $f_i^*$ we need to maximize over $x_i$ also. So i have confusion

Comment: They assume that you already have computed the function $f^*$.

Comment: @amsmath thanks for your comment. I know $v$ is a scalar. But I have confusion about computation of $f_i^*(-va_i)$ which required some optimization also

Comment: @amsmath then I can understand. But is it possible to assume such a thing?

Comment: Dude, the maximization problem as you state it is without doubt a single variable problem. That does not say anything about how many variables you need to compute the function that is to be maximized.

Comment: @amsmath actually $f_i^*$ is the conjugate function of $f_i$ so according to the definition of conjugate function we have to perform maximization over the argument of $f_i$ which in this case is $x_i$. You can see the definition of conjugate function in Convex Optimization book

Comment: I know what the conjugate function is. Have you read my comment?

Comment: @amsmath yes I have read it. But I think if we have multivariable problem and if we maximize over some of the variables except one. Later if we write as a maximization problem of single variable then will it be write to say that its a single variable problem

Comment: @FrankMoses Sorry, I can't understand a word of what you're saying.

Comment: As amsmath has said, the statement is simply that the second optimization problem is over a single variable $v$, if you assume that $f^*_i$ are known functions. You are correct that the definition of conjugate function involves another optimization problem, but the statement about "single variable optimization" is interpreting $f^*_i$ as known functions.